# Java 7 Regex and named groups with multiple patterns

Tags: java, regex, grouping

I have two different sources feeding input files to my application. Their filename patterns differ, yet they contain common information that I want to retrieve.

Using regex named groups seemed convenient, as it allows for maximum code factorization, however it has its limits, as I cannot concat the two patterns if they use the same group names.

#### Example:

In other words, this:

```
String PATTERN_GROUP_NAME   = "name";
String PATTERN_GROUP_DATE   = "date";
String PATTERN_IMPORT_1     = "(?<" + PATTERN_GROUP_NAME + ">[a-z]{3})_(?<" + PATTERN_GROUP_DATE + ">[0-9]{14})_(stuff stuf)\\.xml";
String PATTERN_IMPORT_2     = "(stuff stuf)_(?<" + PATTERN_GROUP_DATE + ">[0-9]{14})_(?<" + PATTERN_GROUP_NAME + ">[a-z]{3})_(other stuff stuf)\\.xml";
Pattern universalPattern    = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_IMPORT_1 + "|" + PATTERN_IMPORT_2);
try {
  DirectoryStream<Path> list = Files.newDirectoryStream(workDirectory);
  for (Path file : list) {
    Matcher matcher = universalPattern.matcher(file.getFileName().toString());
    name = matcher.group(PATTERN_GROUP_NAME);
    fileDate = dateFormatter.parseDateTime(matcher.group(PATTERN_GROUP_DATE));
    (...)
```

will fail with a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` because the named capturing groups are already defined.

**What would be the most efficient / elegant way of solving this problem?**

Edits:

It goes without saying, but the two patterns I can match my input files against are different enough so no input file can match both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Use two patterns - then group names can be equal.***

You asked for efficient and elegant. Theoretical one pattern could be more efficient, but that is irrelevant here.

First: the code will be slightly longer, but better readable - a weakness of regex. That makes it better maintainable.

In pseudo-code:

```
Matcher m = firstPattern.matcher ...
if (!m.matches()) {
    m = secondPattern.matcher ...
    if (!m.matches()) {
        continue;
    }
}
name = m.group(NAME_GROUP);
...
```

*(Everyone want to do too clever coding, but simplicity may be called for.)*

Comment: I went with this in the end. I enjoy writing "clever" code, but I guess it's one of these cases where KISS is best. +1 for "Everyone want to do too clever coding, but simplicity may be called for.", made me smile :)

Comment: @SilverQuettier this was such a simplistic answer I had not much hope for acceptance. Nice to encounter professionalism.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Joop Eggen's opinion. **Two patterns are simple & easily maintainable.**
Just for **fun**, and give you one pattern implementation for your specific case. (a liitle bit longer & ugly.)

```
String[] inputs = {
        "stuff stuf_20111130121212_abc_other stuff stuf.xml",
        "stuff stuf_20111130151212_def_other stuff stuf.xml",
        "abc_20141220202020_stuff stuf.xml", 
        "def_20140820202020_stuff stuf.xml"
        };    
    String lookAhead = "(?=([a-z]{3}_[0-9]{14}_stuff stuf\\.xml)|(stuff stuf_[0-9]{14}_[a-z]{3}_other stuff stuf\\.xml))";
    String onePattern = lookAhead
            + "((?<name>[a-z]{3})_(other stuff stuf)?|(stuff stuf_)?(?<date>[0-9]{14})_(stuff stuf)?){2}\\.xml";


Pattern universalPattern = Pattern.compile(onePattern);
for (String input : inputs) {
    Matcher matcher = universalPattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        //System.out.println(matcher.group());
        String name = matcher.group("name");
        String fileDate = matcher.group("date");
        System.out.println("name : " + name + " fileDate: "
                + fileDate);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
name : abc fileDate: 20111130121212
name : def fileDate: 20111130151212
name : abc fileDate: 20141220202020
name : def fileDate: 20140820202020
```

Actually, in your case, the "lookAhead" is not necessary. Since in one pattern, you can't assign two goups with the same name. Therefore, normally, you need to revise your pattern.
From AB|BA  ---> (A|B){2}